# Add extra text/content to select menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I am trying to create a drop-down-select menu that users can be selected from. I want to also have the number of projects they are assigned to displayed next to their name

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name

  belongs_to :department
  has_many :project_assignments
```

.

```
class ProjectAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :project_id, :active, :notes

  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :projects_count
  belongs_to :project
end
```

.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :program_id, :title, :status, :topic_number, :award_number, :task_data_attributes, :user_ids, :technical_poc_id, :contacts_attributes, :project_fields_attributes, :division_id, :company_name

  attr_accessor :old_project_id

  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :users, through: :project_assignments
```

.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p>New Assignment</p>
  <%= form_for @project.project_assignments.new, url: program_project_assignments_path(@program, @project), html: { id: 'staff-form' } do |f|  %>
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :full_name), {}, class: 'form-control input-sm', placeholder: 'User' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "project_id",nil,:value => @project.id %>
    <%= f.submit 'Assign', class: 'btn-gray' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

All the above code is just excerpts from their respective files. The above html works for populating the drop-down with names, but obviously no code there is attempting to add the number of assigned projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.collect{|u|["#{u.full_name} #{u.project_assignments.count}", u.id]}), {}, class: 'form-control input-sm', placeholder: 'User' %>
```

It will be efficient to load the users and eager load project assignment in your controller

```
@users = User.includes(:project_assignment).all
```

Comment: it worked other than "#{u.full_name u.project_assignments.count}". Changing that to"#{u.full_name} #{u.project_assignments.count}" worked